# DialogFlow's intent hexadecimal code recognition

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am currently making an inteligent assistant with DialogFlow that takes your table reservation for an italian restaurant.

When the reservation its done it shows you a 6 character hexadecimal number:
[image]

I am trying to do a 'reservation check' intent, where the bot will ask your reservation code, and if its correct, it will show you the data of the reservation (stored inside a string array when the reservation was done)

The problem is that no existing entity seems to recognize hexadecimal numbers, and i can't make a new entity that includes all possible combinations of a random generator.

Is there anyway i can make this work? Should i go for another way of validation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

reservation code @sys.any

as the Training Phrase and put it in separate context to ensure better matching.